# How to implement error handling in ANTLR4

Tags: java, error-handling, antlr4

I have the following grammar for parsing first-order logic formulas applied over graphs:

```
grammar Graph;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
* PARSER RULES
*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

input
: 
formula EOF
;

formula
:
TRUE 
| FALSE 
| formula AND formula
| formula OR formula
| quantifier formula
| ST condition
;


condition
:
atom EQUALS QUOTE? (assignment | atom) QUOTE?
;

quantifier 
:
(FOREACH | EXISTS) variable IN domain
;

domain
:
(GRAPH_A | GRAPH_B)
;

atom
:
variable DOT property
;


variable
:   
(nodev | edgev)
;


nodev
:
(NODE | NODE1)
;

edgev
:
(EDGE | EDGE1)
;

property
:
(COLOR | VALUE)
;

assignment
:
(COLORTYPE | NUMBER)
;


/*------------------------------------------------------------------
* LEXER RULES
*------------------------------------------------------------------*/

TRUE : 'True' ;

FALSE : 'False' ;

AND : '&' ;

OR : '|' ;

ST : '->' ; 

EXISTS  : 'Exists' ;

FOREACH : 'Foreach' ;

NODE : 'node' ;

NODE1 : 'node1' ;

EDGE : 'edge' ;

EDGE1 : 'edge1' ;

IN : 'in' ;

GRAPH_A : 'GraphA' ;

GRAPH_B : 'GraphB' ;

EQUALS : '=' ;

DOT : '.' ;

COLOR : 'color' ;

VALUE : 'value' ;

NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+ (DOT ('0'..'9')+)? ;

QUOTE : '\'' ;

COLORTYPE : ('a'..'z')+ ;

WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip ;
```

I believe that this is the final version of my grammar so now I want to specify some error handling for the input. The problem is that I don't know how. What I know is that after I parse the input I can iterate over the generated AST and this is the place to add the error handling.

If the parse fails, return the parse exception; otherwise, I have specified the following cases for returning error message.

1. There can't be 1 quantifier followed by `-> condition` (this is a formula element) where   condition is equal to `atom=atom`. In other words, if there is only `quantifier` then `condition` should be equal to `atom EQUALS assignment`.
2. If there are 2 quantifiers the first should start with `FOREACH`
3. The variable(s) in the quantifiers should be used in the `condition` statement
4. There can't be more than two quantifiers on the left hand-side of the expression (because in the app I am developing there are only two graphs). So if the number of quantifiers is greater then two return error as well
5. If there are 2 quantifiers then they should have different variables bound on them

For example, the first case should be raised when as an input we have

```
Exists node in GraphA -> node.color = node1.color
```

because `node1` isn't specified in the left hand-side of the expression.

An example for the second case would be the following input

```
Exists node in GraphA Exists node1 in GraphB -> node.color = node1.color
```

So my question is do I have to implement all the error checking over the generated parse tree or I can specify some of it in the grammar using some java code. If the error handling should happen after the input is parsed what functionality of ANTLR 4 can I use in order to implement the error cases? Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think that the `visitor` class would be able to solve my problems. When I am traversing the parse tree i will add the elements I am interested in a data structure (probably a `HashMap` or something) and then I will apply the required logic. Am I in the right direction or I am missing some fundamental knowledge regarding ANTLR?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll probably want to implement these semantic checks in a listener, in combination with helper visitors. Here are some examples.

#### Rule: The variables in the `quantifier` should be used in the `condition`

Implementation:

1. Create a visitor that returns the variables used by a specified parse tree node. You'll want to override [`defaultResult()`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.html#defaultResult%28%29) and [`aggregateResult(T, T)`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.html#aggregateResult%28T,%20T%29) to do most of the work for you, and then override `visitNodev` and `visitEdgev` to handle the specific variables in use.
2. In your listener, override the `enterFormula` method. In this method, if `ctx.quantifier()` is not null, then use your visitor to get the list of variables declared in `ctx.quantifier()` and the list of variables used in `ctx.formula()`.
3. Report an error as appropriate based on the two results.

#### Rule: If there are 2 quantifiers then they should have different variables bound on them

Implementation:

1. Start with the visitor described in step 1 of the previous rule implementation.
2. In your listener, override the `enterFormula` method. In the method, if `ctx.quantifier()` is not null, then you need to get a collection of all the other `QuantifierContext` instances underneath the tree returned by `ctx.formula()`. You can do this by calling [`XPath.findAll(ctx.formula(), "//quantifier", parser)`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/xpath/XPath.html#findAll%28org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTree,%20java.lang.String,%20org.antlr.v4.runtime.Parser%29).
3. Use the visitor described above to gather a list of variables declared in each of the linked `QuantifierContext` instances. If any of the sets overlap, report an error as appropriate.

#### Rule: If there are 2 quantifiers the first should start with `FOREACH`

Implementation:

Use the listener pattern described in the previous step to locate cases where a formula contains more than one `quantifier`. If the first of these formulas has `ctx.quantifier().FOREACH() == null` emit an error as appropriate.

#### Rule: There can't be more than two quantifiers...

Implementation:

Update the implementation of the 2nd rule above to report an error if `XPath.findAll` returns more than one `QuantifierContext` in the `formula` for a `quantifier`.

#### Rule: Quantifier condition restriction

Implementation:

First, create a [`ParseTreePattern`](http://www.antlr.org/api/Java/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/pattern/ParseTreePattern.html) object.

```
String patternString = "<quantifier> -> <condition>";
ParseTreePattern pattern =
    parser.compileParseTreePattern(patternString, GraphParser.RULE_formula);
```

Then, find all instances of this pattern in your parse tree.

```
List<ParseTreeMatch> matches = pattern.findAll(tree, "//formula");
```

Validating the matches is then rather simple.

```
for (ParseTreeMatch match : matches) {
  ConditionContext condition = (ConditionContext)match.get("condition");
  if (condition.assignment() == null) {
    // TODO: report error here
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer. Can you just explain me how to use XPath properly. What I do in the `enterFormula()` is `Collection<ParseTree> q =  XPath.findAll(ctx,"//quantifer",parser);` where `ctx` is of type `FormulaContext` and every time I end up with `NullPointerException`. Do you have any idea why this happens?

Comment: You meant `quantifier`, not `quantifer`. You should create an issue no GitHub so we can fix this behavior (with a better error message) for the next release: https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues

Comment: Will do. Is there any other way to query `FormulaContext` in order to end up with the count of `Quantifier` elements?