# antlr4 error handling doesn't even compile

Tags: antlr4

I followed the instructions for error handling at the antlr website http://www.antlr2.org/doc/err.html (it says antlr2 but I couldn't find an alternative for antlr4) and wrote the exception handling for my rule as below.

```
subStmt : 
(visibility WS)? (STATIC WS)? SUB WS? ambiguousIdentifier (WS? argList)? endOfStatement
block? 
END_SUB
;
exception
catch [RecognitionException ex] {

}
```

But when I try to generate the Parser for the grammar it fails as below:
java -jar ../Downloads/antlr-4.7-complete.jar vba.g4 -package vba -o out
error(50): vba.g4:500:4: syntax error: 'catch' came as a complete surprise to me while matching rule preamble

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Antlr4 is quite different to Antlr2. Start by having a look at this question (and the answer):

[How to implement error handling in ANTLR4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613421/how-to-implement-error-handling-in-antlr4)

Update with a simple approach:

For error reporting, the basic approach is to make a class that implements the `ANTLRErrorListener` interface. `BaseErrorListener` has empty implementations for all the methods so you only need to implement the ones you care about. You probably care about `syntaxError()` the most.

On your parser object, call `removeErrorListeners()` to clear the internal error listener, and then call `addErrorListener()` with an instance of the class you want to handle your errors.

You will then get `syntaxError()` calls on that class when errors are encountered during a parse.

The other methods might (or might not) let you do what you want to do; I haven't used this interface to recover from parse errors.

For recovering from particular errors, you can implement a class with the  `ANTLRErrorStrategy` interface. That gets complicated; see `DefaultErrorStrategy` for the default implementation.

A very simple approach is to deal with the possible errors in your grammar. Not sure how far you can go with this, but this is likely to be the easiest approach.

Comment: That example seems very complicated. My case might be to simply ignore errors in some rule (I need to accept a input with errors). Is there not an antlr4 error handling documentation?

Comment: @HughDarling Fair enough -- I extended my answer a bit.